# Problem with writing .dat files using Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran95

I am reading a .txt file and writing to a .dat file for use in GrADS.
The .txt file contains 1D data, and my program reads all 123 lines correctly as I checked by printing on screen. However, the result .dat file only contains the very first line of data, the rest are all zeros. How can I fix this? Did I set the dimensions in `write` incorrectly?

Here is my code:

```
program convert
integer,parameter::nlon=1,nlat=1,nz=123
real,dimension(nlat,nlon,nz)::pr
integer::ilon,ilat,iz

open(2,file='2020082100_1.txt',form='formatted',status='old')

INQUIRE(IOLENGTH=LREC) pr

open(3,file='2020082100_1.dat',form='unformatted', &
access='direct',recl=LREC)

do iz=1,nz
  do ilat=nlat,1,-1
    read(2,*) (pr(ilat,ilon,iz),ilon=1,1)
  end do
end do

IREC=1
do iz=1,nz
  write(3,rec=irec) ((pr(ilat,ilon,iz),ilon=1,nlon),ilat=1,nlat)
  IREC=IREC+1
end do

close(2)
close(3)

end program convert
```

For example, the first few lines of the .txt file are:

```
30.7
29.4
25.9
24.2
24.4
...
```

However, the .dat file contains this:

```
30.7
0
0
0
0
...
```

Comment: How do you verify the content of the .dat file?

Comment: I open a corresponding .ctl file in GrADS and plot it out, also by setting to a specific x,y,z coordinates to check them. Then I found out my code only wrote the “30.7” into the .dat file, with another 122 zeros.

Comment: I'm not familiar with GrADS, are you sure it's reading with the right record length, when I change your program to reopen the .dat file at the end, and read it and write it back to the console it looks OK

Comment: I see the problem now, it wrote everything on the latitude-axis, instead of the z-axis that I wanted. Now I am sure that all data wrote successfully, just not in the right way. I'll try to see how can I fix this.

Answer (score 1):

So after tinkering with the code for a few hours, I figured out how to fix it myself.

Since all the data is writing on the wrong axis, I simply need to change a single line of code:

from this:`write(3,rec=irec) ((pr(ilat,ilon,iz),ilon=1,nlon),ilat=1,nlat)`

to this: `write(3,rec=iz) ((pr(iz,ilon,ilat),ilon=1,nlon),ilat=1,nlat)`.

By changing this it completely worked. I did actually set the dimensions in `write` incorrectly.